# Kotlin/Java: Add multiple items to a Builder class that only allows one .add() at a time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

Problem: I'm using an AWS DynamoDb Enhanced Java client V2 in Kotlin (the details of the client might not be important), where I want to make a `BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest` containing a bunch of requests. The standard usage according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html#dynamodb-enhanced-mapper-batchitems) goes:

```
val batchWriteItemEnhancedRequest = BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
    .addWriteBatch(
        WriteBatch.builder(MyClass::class.java)
            .mappedTableResource(myMappedTable)
            .addPutItem(putRequest1)
            .addPutItem(putRequest2)
            .addPutItem(putRequest3)
            .build()
    )
    .build()
```

Obviously this can't handle an anonymous list of `putRequest` items, only some known discrete values like `putRequest1` and `putRequest2`.

The builder for `WriteBatch` doesn't seem to allow adding lists of requests: [doc](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/model/WriteBatch.Builder.html)

The only way to do this, as I can see, is to make a for-loop that goes:

```
var writeBatchBuilder = WriteBatch.builder(MyClass::class.java)
    .mappedTableResource(myMappedTable)

for (request in putItemRequests){
    writeBatchBuilder = writeBatchBuilder.addPutItem(request)
}

val writeBatch = writeBatchBuilder.build()
```

Which seems horrible to me. There's got to be a more idiomatic way to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an instance of `WriteBatch.Builder`, there's no explicit need to chain the DSL, so your `writeBatchBuilder` can be a `val`. Each builder function mutates the internal state of the `WriteBatch.Builder` instance, and the returned value is just for convenience - [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/e377518b08ccc2cd9cc32be74345064b2fadee64/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/model/WriteBatch.java#L228-L232).

You can therefore simplify your for-loop and make `writeBatchBuilder` a `val`:

```kotlin
val writeBatchBuilder = WriteBatch.builder(MyClass::class.java)
    .mappedTableResource(myMappedTable)

for (request in putItemRequests){
    writeBatchBuilder.addPutItem(request)
}

val writeBatch = writeBatchBuilder.build()
```

##### Scope function

Going one step further, [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) are a nice way of converting Java DSLs into something more Kotlin-esque.

(For a more visual guide to scope functions, and Kotlin in general, check out https://typealias.com/start/kotlin-scopes-and-scope-functions/)

[`apply {}`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply) will turn the created `WriteBatch.Builder` into the receiver, meaning you don't need to have a variable for the builder, you can just use `this`.

```kotlin
val writeBatch = WriteBatch.builder(MyClass::class.java).apply {
  mappedTableResource(myMappedTable)

  putItemRequests.forEach { request -> 
    addPutItem(request)
  }
}.build()
```

(I also changed the for loop into a `forEach {}` - which is more Kotlin-ey.)

##### Custom helper function

The next improvement is to encapsulate the `apply {}` logic inside of a helper function, `writeBatchBuilder()`, so the boilerplate is hidden away, which makes re-using the function easier.

Using `inline` and `reified T` means there's no need to define `::class.java` every time - instead the class can be defined as a type-parameter, and the class can be omitted if Kotlin can infer the type.

Note that the receiver of the `builder` arg is `WriteBatch.Builder`, just like how the `apply {}` scope function changes the receiver to be the builder.

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> buildWriteBatch(
  builder: WriteBatch.Builder<T>.() -> Unit
) : WriteBatch<T> {
  return WriteBatch.builder(T::class.java).apply(builder).build()
}
```

Example usage:

```kotlin
val writeBatch = buildWriteBatch<MyClass> {
  mappedTableResource(myMappedTable)

  putItemRequests.forEach { request -> 
    addPutItem(request)
  }
}


// no need for explicit typing on buildWriteBatch - Kotlin can infer the type
val writeBatch2: WriteBatch<MyClass> = buildWriteBatch {}
```

(For examples of this approach in Kotlin stdlib, see [the collection builder functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#create-with-collection-builder-functions))

Answer (score 2):

In this case  [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) function may come handy. Let's assume, that `WriteBatch.builder(MyClass::class.java)` has type `WriteBatch.Builder` maybe with some generics, which is hard to say for example.

```
val writeBatch = WriteBatch.builder(MyClass::class.java)
    .mappedTableResource(myMappedTable)
    .addItems(putItemRequests)
    .build()
// I did use Any for items type, change it according to your need
fun WriteBatch.Builder.addItems(items: List<Any>): WriteBatch.Builder {
    items.forEach { item -> addPutItem(item) }
    // in case addPutItem(item) returns a new builder instance just store it in the variable and return it at the end.
    return this
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'm getting an IDE error, though, that's complaining `addItems` is returning a Unit data type. I suppose the extension function should be made to return the builder object itself. How would I do this? `return this` seems to work, but I don't know if this is standard.

Comment: A nice shortcut for `doSomething(); return this` is `apply { doSomething() }`

Comment: Sorry, seems my example was not complete. Yes return type should be builder type, which is accesible via this. Return same builder instance is usually Fine. Depends on builder implementation tho. Majority implementation use same builder instance whole time. Minority makes builder copy.